# Що означає "підупала маринарка"?

Tags: значення-слів

В селі часто чула вислів "підупала маринарка" в значенні стало сумно, невесело. Пошукавши на просторах інтернету з'ясувала, що маринарка - це піджак, жакет (в [етимологічному словнику](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf) також є походження цього слова -  [маренатка] «короткий
жіночий жакет, бр. [марнатка] «курт­ка»; - запозичення з польської мови;
n. marynarka «чоловіча куртка», [marynatka]
«матроський одяг» пов'язані з іт.marinara «бушлат із відлогою,. матро­ська куртка», похідним від marina «мор­ський флот»). Це значення даного слова не дуже співпадає з виразом *підупала маринарка*. Можливо є ще якесь значення слова, яке б пояснювало цей вираз?

Comment: Може вставні плечі опустились, також інші частини, які мають форму. І вигляд вже не той.

Comment: [Віктор Морозов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Морозов_Віктор_Євгенович) у пісні ["Прошу пані"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K430nYYbXbg) має слова *Виджу пані змерзла – прошу маринарку.*

Comment: На UaModna є [стаття про це слово](https://uamodna.com/articles/marynarka/). *Маринарка - ні це не український варіант соусу маринара, і навіть не варіант жіночого імені. Це слівце означає піджак або жіночий жакетик.*

Answer (score 2):

СУМ-11

> [Підупалий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidupalyj) 1. Дієпр. акт. мин. ч. до підупасти. 2. у знач. прикм.
>   Фізично слабіший, позбавлений минулої сили, міцності.
>
> [Підупати, аю, аєш, недок., ПІДУПАСТИ, аду, адеш, док.](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidupadaty) 1. Ставати
>   слабішим; дещо позбавлятися минулої сили, міцності.//  Ставати гіршим,
>   псуватися (про настрій, душевний стан і т. ін.).

Значення слова "маринарка" є в інших словниках

[Лексикон львівський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53404/1064429.html)

> марина́рка (мариню́рка) піджак (м, ср, ст)

[ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53404/903190.html)

> маринарка 
>   -и, ж. , зах. Жакет, піджак

[Словник галицьких говірок](http://slovopedia.org.ua/100/53404/1042022.html)

> маринарка  піджак

[Укр. літ. мова на Буковині](http://slovopedia.org.ua/103/53404/1077336.html)

> Марина́рка. Морський флот. *При заприсяженю маринаркиу Вільгельмсгафен
>   виголосив цісар німецкий слідуючі характеристичні слова (Б., 1895, 8,
>   3); Міністерство війни і маринарки наразі не обсаджені і управляє ними
>   тим часом президент міністрів Рібо (Б., 1895, 5, 4); Дня 20. с. м.
>   поплине ся міжнародна ескадра в Гольтенав, де вечером в академиї
>   маринарки буде баль (Б., 1895, 45, 3)*// пол. marynarka - 1) флот, 2)
>   піджак; нім. die Marine - військово- морський флот; порівн. маринарка,
>   фр. -1) короткий сертук, піджак, 2) фльота (гал., СЧС, 517).

*Можливо, **"підупала маринарка"** означає **"погіршився настрій у морського флоту"**.*

Comment: Можливо, просто піджак зсунувся вниз, відповідаючи похмурому станові власника?

Comment: @P.Vowk все можливо!

Comment: та невже??)))))